# How to generate message classes from new custom FIX dictionary

Tags: c++, quickfix

There is [a way](http://www.quickfixj.org/confluence/display/qfj/Custom+Message+Generation+-+Packaging) to do this in QuickFIX/j.

Is there a way to do this in QuickFIX c++?

Comment: can you explain simply what you need?

Comment: @tAmirNaghizadeh: He is pretty clear in what he needs.

Comment: @Qsiris:  Please edit your post to include a textual description that describes what you're trying to do.  Links die over time, and without the description this question will have no meaning if the link is dead.

Comment: What isn't clear about my question? The link included is not mandatory for the question. The question is clear by itself.

Comment: @Qsiris: Nothing is wrong. Most people just have no idea what the hell you are talking about :-) Of course you could have written a poem in your question, but for those who know FIX and its implementations it is pretty clear. So no worries, just not a mainstream.

Comment: But they closed my question and down voted it. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have never tried it myself, but if you download the source code, you will find a `generate.sh` file inside a "spec" directory that contains the following:

```
./generate_c++.sh
./generate_net.sh
ruby Generator.rb
```

The first script simply invokes a bunch of `xsltproc` commands in order to generate values and a message dispatching logic (aka cracker). But the majority of the generation is done using `Generator.rb` script (the main logic for C++ is in `GeneratorCPP.rb`). So what you have to do is to modify an existing XML spec file like `FIX42.xml`, run the generator and build source code.

Comment: If my dictionary file has a different name, will it be recognised? Inside it's mostly the same with FIX44.xml, but the file name is different.

Comment: @Qsiris: Nope, I don't think so. If you look at last lines in Generator.rb, it goes specifically through file names 4.[0...4] and 5.[0...2]. But you can modify that file yourself, say, for a file named "MYFIX.4.2.xml", add a line like "aggregateFields( "MYFIX", 4, 2, 0, aggregator )".

Comment: @Qsiris - I don't believe the script would be so contrived to deter you from changing it.

Comment: @VladLazarenko I've managed to generate the classes and now I have to build the library again, but I get errors. What else do I need to modify in order to compile?

Comment: @Qsiris: Depends what errors you are getting? Do you get them w/o generating your own stuff?

Comment: The errors I had were because I commented part of the Generator.rb. It all worked well once I cleaned, ran Generator.rb again and compiled.