# How to redefine QuickFix classes for custom groups?

Tags: python, ant, quickfix

I am using QuickFix with Python to connect with an idiosyncratic data provider. They have defined a new repeating group `NoChartData`, which I cannot read because the way I define a group in QuickFix is, for example, `group = fix42.MarketDataIncrementalRefresh().NoMDEntries()`. When I replace `NoMDEntries()` with `NoChartData()` I get an attribute error because `NoChartData()` does not exist.

I've got some vague idea that I need to rebuild the QuickFix classes, which I read about here:

http://quickfix-j.364392.n2.nabble.com/How-to-avoid-ordering-group-fields-td7132898.html

I found ant.jar in the quickfix/lib/jar folder but have no idea how to run it.

I have modified the Data Dictionary and everything should be fine if I can just figure out how to create a custom group. Maybe there is an easier way?

BTW: 
I know there is a related question on this site.
This guy got downvoted and his question closed for asking a perfectly clear question but not explaining it: [How to generate message classes from new custom FIX dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13567544/how-to-generate-message-classes-from-new-custom-fix-dictionary) (But I need to do this in Python and so the associated links are not helpful.)

---**UPDATE 24 SEP '14**--

I have ant installed but am not sure how to use it! The obvious thing, to apply it to my Data Dictionary, does not have the desired result.

> c:\quickfix\spec>ant -f FIX42_CTS.xml Buildfile:
>   c:\quickfix\spec\FIX42_CTS.xml
>
> BUILD FAILED c:\quickfix\spec\FIX42_CTS.xml:1: Unexpected element
>   "{}fix" {antlib:org.apache. tools.ant}fix
>
> Total time: 0 seconds

Maybe this question can help other QF users inexperienced with Java and Ant.

Comment: I'm confused.  Are you using QF/C++ or QF/J?  Seems like you're using the latter, but with Python bindings that I did not know existed.  Jython maybe?

Comment: I always assumed it was C++. I have no idea how it could be Java. I got it here: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ . Why do you think I am using QF/J? Any easy way to tell which one it is?

Comment: Ew.  Yep, it's the C++ one.  `ant` is a Java build tool, so that's why I assumed Java, and your link is from the QF/j mail list.

Comment: Sorry for the misleading link! I had no idea Ant only worked for QF/J

Comment: To be fair, there's no reason you couldn't use Ant for non-java stuff, but it's geared for and implemented in Java.

Answer (score 2):

There's basic instructions on how to generate QF/j source here on the QF/j wiki's User FAQ:
http://www.quickfixj.org/confluence/display/qfj/User+FAQ

(Strangely, this FAQ currently has two questions about this that are mostly the same.  I will have to look into combining them.  This is a little embarrassing, as it appears I am the only editor of that page. :) )

You'll have to edit your DataDictionary XML file.  The structure of that file is pretty simple; spend a few minutes skimming through it so you understand the layout.  (First is a big section on message definitions, followed by a big section of field definitions.  You'll need to edit both sections to add your new Group.)

**EDIT: Turns out you're not using a QF/j-derived build, so this answer is probably not that helpful for you.**

Comment: Yeah, the DD is pretty simple. I've changed it in the past with no problems. Creating new classes from that file to read non-standard messages is new to me though. I've got ant installed, but am not exactly sure how to use it. You say to run the command `ant jar`, but that returns `build.xml does not exist!` The command seems to take a file as an argument. Can I run it from anywhere or do I have to run it from a particular QF folder? Thanks.

Comment: Also -- can I read custom repeating groups without defining them in DD and rebuilding QF? Is there a non-typesafe workaround for reading analogous to making a custom group? (I'm thinking of the example at the end of the FAQ you linked to.)

Comment: If `build.xml` is in your working directory, `ant` should automatically try to use it.  Are you running it in the QF/j project root?  (assuming you're using QF/j)

Comment: Custom *groups* is not too difficult; custom *messages* however get a bit more complex.  For that, you'd also have to put extra detection code in FromApp for this custom message and not call `crack` on it.  In both cases, I think it's much easier to regenerate the QF/j classes and rebuild.  A little effort now will save you some hassle later.

Comment: I did a search, the only place I have build.xml is in `examples/tradeclientgui/banzai/`. Not reassuring. I'm pretty sure I'm not using Java. Also-- I don't think I have `crack`. This is one of the drawbacks of Python I think. I've written all my own message crackers. So maybe the thing to do is just write a workaround. Not sure how to define a custom group though...

Comment: I'm sorry, I think we've reached the end of my expertise on this topic.  I don't have as much hands-on experience with QF/C++, and I've never used the Python bindings.  I still think you should rebuild the engine, but I can't give you direct advice to do so, as I've never done it with C++/Python.

Comment: Wow, I actually stumped you for once! Thanks though, as usual.

Comment: No problem.  Hope you can get past it.