# How do I access QuickFix's generic group api?

Tags: python, quickfix, fix-protocol

I can't find any instances of something that should be simple on the web.

How do I define a **generic** group in QuickFix? I am using the Python bindings and define an MDIncrementalRefresh group like this:

`group = fix42.MarketDataIncrementalRefresh().NoMDEntries()`

But I am trying to read a group that is not standard in FIX4.2, called `NoChartData`. As such I cannot call it because it does not exist in my FIX engine (I am putting off rebuilding QF for now -- see [How to redefine QuickFix classes for custom groups?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26006991/how-to-redefine-quickfix-classes-for-custom-groups?noredirect=1#comment40798356_26006991))

I have some idea that QF has a constructor so I can just create a generic group object and add fields to it. Does anyone know how to define groups on the fly, without rebuilding QF classes?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python is not my strong suit, but this should get the idea across. You can create a new group using  an arbitrary group counter field and an arbitrary group entry delimiter.

The example you give of `NoMDEntries` in a `MarketDataIncrementalRefresh` message would have the counter field = 268 (`NoMDEntries`) and the entry delimiter = 278 (`MDEntryID`).
In that example, you would create the group this way:

`group = quickfix.Group(268, 278)`

To create the non-standard group you need, replace "268" with the appropriate group counter field number, and replace "278" with the appropriate entry delimiter.

To set the group's fields, use the following (again, as an example for `MarketDataIncrementalRefresh`):

```
// Set the MDEntryID, which is the group entry delimiter
group.setField(quickfix.StringField(278, "id1"))

// Set the DeskID
group.setField(quickfix.StringField(284, "tradedesk1"))
```

Comment: This was exactly what I needed, thanks! By specifying the counter field and the entry delimiter as you said, I was able to define the group and get all the fields from it. (I did not need the second part of your example because I was trying to parse a group coming in, not create one going out.) I thought it would be easy! With changes to about two lines of code I was able to conquer this 3 day obstacle. You rock.